# How to convert a byte array into a PDF file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf, pdf-generation, inputstream

I have the following problem trying to create a PDF from an array of byte recovered from a Web Services output object.

So I have the following situation:

```
OutFat outFat = callServizioContabRighe(dataEM, esercizio, importo, bolla, numDoc, oda, pIva, contratto);

byte[] pdfByteArray = outFat.getPDF();
ByteArrayOutputStream osPdf  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

if(pdfByteArray != null) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfByteArray);
    sun.misc.BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] byteArray64DecodePdf = null;

    try {
        byteArray64DecodePdf =  base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    try {
        osPdf.write(byteArray64DecodePdf);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}

if(osPdf != null && pdfByteArray != null){
    req.getSession().setAttribute("PdfEM", osPdf);       // Usa il PDF recuperato dal WS
}
else {
    req.getSession().setAttribute("PdfEM", createPdfEM.createPdf());    // Crea il PDF
}

if(osPdf != null && pdfByteArray != null){
    this.baos = osPdf;
}
else {
    this.baos = createPdfEM.createPdf();                    // CREA IL PDF
}
```

Ok so I have the **pdfByteArray** that is the byte array retrieved from the outFat object (the webservice output object) and that represent my PDF.

Now I have to use it to build a PDF and show it into a view.

So to create the PDF I do the following steps:

1. I create an **InputStream** object using the **pdfByteArray** retrieved by the WS.
2. I decode it (it is in base64 so I need to decode it).
3. I write the decoded **byteArray64DecodePdf** into the **osPdf** outpustream object.

Then, if the previous steps are successful, I put it into my view (otherwise I create my PDF in an alternative way but this is not related to this question).

The problem is that in my view I can't see the content of my PDF but I only see a grey square rather than it.

What could be the problem?

What can I do to save a local copy of my PDF to try to see it on my local system instead into the browser? So I can understand if the problem is in the conversion or elsewhere

Tnx

Comment: write `byteArray64DecodePdf` to a FileOutputStream to check the contents outside of your program.

Comment: @jtahlborn please can you show me a code snippet?

Comment: it looks just like writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream, just with a FileOutputStream (and a `close()` at the end).